# How to disable multiple select from library in ios

Tags: ios, html, angular, cordova

I'm using this HTML5 input tag to upload files from different devices:

```
<input name="fileInput" type="file" id="fileinput" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
```

I don't want the user to be able to select multiple files from their device library. It works fine on android but in ios the user can select more than one file. Is there any way to disable multiple select on ios?

Comment: You still can check if the user has chosen only one file in your component

Comment: Yes, but that's not the solution I want. If the user has chosen more than one file then the system either have to warn the user that they only can upload one file at time or selecting one file from the chosen files. The best solution would be if the user only can select one file in the devices library

Comment: Well, I can't help you on that, sorry. But let me remind you that just by adding `multiple` to an input file tag, the user will be able to send several files. And if you don't control them in your component, there will be some trouble !

Comment: have you got the solution?